# Cloud foundry command to push the same deployment to multiple organization

Tags: cloud-foundry, predix

I am trying to push my deployment to multiple organization space in one cf push could you please let me know whether there is any single command to do so using cf push?

```
cf push ....
```

Is there any option to provide in manifest.yml file?

Comment: Which requirement you want to solve? Why do you want to push the same app to multiple ORGs?
What about pushing the app to one "common" ORG and let it be accessible by other apps in this ORG. With Container to Container networking (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html) it even wouldn't have a round-trip through the internet.

Answer (score 1):

No `cf push` works on given target only. 
For your use case, a the `targets` plugin may help. Plugins are available on https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org. You still will need some shell scripting to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no single command you can use to deploy the same application to different Orgs.
The only workaround you can use is - create shell script to target different Org once you are done with push to one Org.